# Errors with WWW-Auth

Tags: php, authentication, web

With this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
    isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    elseif (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $salt1 = "qm&h*";
        $salt2 = "pg!@";
        $token = md5("$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

        if ($token == $row[3])
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $un_temp;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pw_temp;
            $_SESSION['forename'] = $row[0];
            $_SESSION['surname']  = $row[1];
            echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi $row[0],
                you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
            die;
        }
        else die("Invalid username/password combination");
    }
    else die("Invalid username/password combination");
}
else
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Please enter your username and password");
}

function mysql_entities_fix_string($string)
{
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
}   

function mysql_fix_string($string)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
?>
```

I am getting the popup for auth continually, even after inserting the correct username and passsword.

All php syntax checkers have said this is fine - Any ideas on what the problem is?

SQL Contents here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z23Qq.png

Username = 'bsmith';
Password = 'mysecret';